# Как сделать из множества строк одну? python

Tags: python

У меня есть текстовый документ, и в нем много строк и в каждой строке по одному слову. Мне нужно чтобы в одну переменную записались все эти слова в одну строку через запятую.

---

### input

1. Hello
2. hello
3. world
4. world

---

### output

1. Hello, hello, world, world

Comment: Числа тоже есть в файле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лови:

```
a = ','.join(open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8').read().split('\n'))
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Можно так сделать:

```py
f = open(file_name) # file_name - имя файлы
data =', '.join([string.strip() for string in f])
f.close()
print(data)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Эта функция позволит взять файл и получить из него массив по разделителю:

```
#filelink - путь до файла в виде строки
#razdelitel - символ, по которому разделять
def SplitFIle(filelink, razdelitel):
    file = open(filelink, 'r') #откроем файл на чтение
    text = file.read() #возьмем от туда текст
    file.close() #закроем файл
    text = text.split(razdelitel) #разобьем по разделителю
    return (text) #вернем массив данных
list1 = SplitFIle('somefile.txt', '\n') #указали ссылку на файл и разделителель (в данном случае - перенос строки)
list1 = str(list1) #если вам обязательно нужен тип данных "строка" в итоге, если нужен массив, то удалите эту строку
print(list1)
```

Comment: `close()` вызовите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Стас угу, скобки забыл, спасибо